# WinXP on VPC - Unable to change the way users log on or off

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

On my Windows 7 computer, I have set up a new Windows XP VPC. In the VPC window, when I click Ctrl+Alt+Del, I see Windows Task Manager. As per [this Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281980), I can change this behavior to show the regular Windows Security window. But while making this change, I get the following error:

```
--------------
User Accounts
--------------
Fast User Switching cannot be turned off from a remote connection to this
computer. Log on to the computer locally to turn off Fast User Switching.
--------------
OK   
--------------
```

Is there any way I can fix this setting?

Comment: Just to say, you wont get much interest unless you start accepting answers, this is how the community works

Comment: There are no answers to my questions.  Systech, what is your comment doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you figured it out. If not, turn off Integration Features in the Tools menu of VPC.

Comment: Yep, I verified this and its working fine.  I didn't realize that Integration Features is the one which fixed it.  Thanks for hinting this.